# When is a triangular structure called non-degenerate?

Tags: lie-algebras, quantum-groups

> Let $(\mathfrak {g}, [\cdot, \cdot], \delta)$ be a triangular Lie bialgebra with classical $r$-matrix $r \in \bigwedge^2 \mathfrak {g}.$ In such a case we say that $r$ is a triangular structure on $\mathfrak {g}.$ A triangular structure $r$ on $\mathfrak {g}$ is said to be non-degenerate if it induces non-degenerate map $\underline {r} : \mathfrak {g}^{\ast} \longrightarrow \mathfrak {g}.$

This definition is given by Pavel Etingof in his lecture notes on compact quantum groups. But I don't know what's the map $\underline {r} : \mathfrak {g}^{\ast} \longrightarrow \mathfrak {g}$ induced by $r$ which the author is talking about. Could anyone please clear it up a bit?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You have not explained what a triangular structure etc. is but fortunately we don't need it. An element $r\in \bigwedge^2V$ induces a map $\bar{r}:V^*\to V$ by linearly extending the maps $v\wedge w(f) = f(v)w - f(w)v$. This has nothing to do with Lie bialgebras and everything to do with viewing tensors as multilinear maps.

Comment: @Callum$:$ And what is meant by non-degeneracy of this map?

Comment: Bijectivity. As an example, $v\wedge w$ defined as above has rank $2$ so is not bijective in general. Note also $r$ can also be viewed as an alternating form on $\mathfrak{g}^*$ and nondegeneracy is exactly nondegeneracy of this form (so it is then a symplectic form on $\mathfrak{g}^*$).

Comment: @Callum$:$ What is the alternating form it corresponds to and what do you mean by symplectic forms on $\mathfrak {g}^{\ast}\ $? I haven't familiar with the symplectic forms yet. Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: A symplectic form $\omega$ is a bilinear map $V \times V \to \mathbb{F}$ which is alternating ($\omega(a,a) = 0$), and nondegenerate ($\omega(a,b) = 0$ for all $b$ implies $a=0$). We can construct the alternating form again by linear combination of the simple ones: $v \wedge w(f,g) := \left|\begin{matrix}f(v)&f(w)\\g(v)&g(w)\end{matrix}\right|$

Comment: @Callum$:$ What does non-degeneracy of Poisson structure mean?

Comment: @Callum$:$ Another thing is that Etingof mentioned that if $r$ is non-degenerate then $r^{-1}$ exists as an element of $\bigwedge^2 \mathfrak {g}^{\ast}.$ If $r$ is non-degenerate then according to what you said we have $r^{-1} : \mathfrak {g} \longrightarrow \mathfrak {g}^{\ast}$ is an isomorphism. From here how to express $r^{-1}$ as an element of $\bigwedge^2 \mathfrak {g}^{\ast}\ $?

Answer (score 0):

For all bivector $r\in\wedge^2V$, one can define a map $\underline{r} : V^\ast\to V$ as follows
$$\forall\alpha,\beta\in V^\ast,\ \beta\left(\underline{r}(\alpha)\right):=\underline{r}(\alpha,\beta)$$
$r$ is nondegenrate iff $\underline{r}$ is invertible.This implies that the dimension of $V$ is even, since $\underline{r}$ is skew-symmetric and therefore has an even rank.

This is similar to the definition of a symplectic form.